# Java while loop assisstance

Tags: java, while-loop

I am having 2 main issues. the first is I cannot make it loop back around for another persons details to be input. the second is I cannot get the shortestHight or shortestName to be recorded. (This is an assignment, I would like help and not the answer please)

> ```
>       {
>           System.out.println("Do you want to enter another person? Y/N ");
>           answer = KB.next();
>
>           while ("yes".equals(answer) || "Yes".equals(answer));
>
>
>           System.out.println("Enter a Name ");
>           name = KB.next();
>           System.out.println("Enter " + name + "'s hight in meters");
>           hight = KB.nextFloat();
>           while (hight <= 0.8 || hight >= 2.5) 
>           {
>               System.out.println(name + "must be between 0.8 and 2.5 meters");
>               System.out.println("Enter " + name + "'s hight in meters");
>               hight = KB.nextFloat();
>           }
>       }
>
>
>       if (hight >= tallestHight) 
>       {
>           tallestHight = hight;
>           tallestName = name;
>       }
>
>
>       else if (hight <= shortestHight) 
>       {
>           shortestHight = hight;
>           shortestName = name;
>       }
>
>
>       System.out.println("The tallest persone is " + tallestName + " at a hight of " + tallestHight);
>
>       System.out.println("And The shortest persone is " + shortestName + " at a hight of " + shortestHight);
>
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you could just use [String#equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I think you cut off the `while` when copy pasting above the `"do you want to enter another person`, that could be important

Comment: `while ("yes".equals(answer) || "Yes".equals(answer));` This will just loop over and over without doing anything. It's equivalent to `while(...) { }`

Comment: You should use `while ("yes".equals(answer) || "Yes".equals(answer)) { .... }`

Comment: while ("yes".equals(answer) || "Yes".equals(answer)); this loop is useless. it wants you to say yes to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is this:

```
while ("yes".equals(answer) || "Yes".equals(answer));
```

This will not result in waiting for another input. It will hang your program as soon as someone enters `Yes` or `yes`. It means while answer is `yes` do nothing. And it will do nothing forever (as `answer` won't change when application is doing nothing).

I think it should look like this:

```
boolean getAnotherPerson = true;
do
{
    System.out.println("Enter a Name ");
    // and so on.
    System.out.println("And The shortest persone is " + shortestName + " at a hight of " + shortestHight);
    System.out.println("Do you want to enter another person? Y/N ");
    answer = KB.next();
    if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) || "no".equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
    {
        getAnotherPerson = false;
    }
} while (getAnotherPerson);
```

And as for shortest person: it will not work with only one person inserted because your using if-else. So you either update highest or shortest person info. Remove the `else` keyword and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use this and make some minor adj for ease of reading/understanding. As for the shortest I used another if statement similar to if (tallestHight == 0 && shortestHight == 0) so the first input was recorded into both tallest and shortest.

Answer (score 0):

Changes are mentioned in comments

```
      String tallestName, shortestName;
      double tallestHight = Double.MIN_VALUE, shortestHight = Double.MAX_VALUE; 
      while (true)
      {
          System.out.println("Do you want to enter another person? Y/N ");
          answer = KB.next();

          // this would loop infinitely if "Yes" or "yes" entered
          // while ("yes".equals(answer) || "Yes".equals(answer));

          // instead you might want this - exit if yes not entered
          if (!(answer.equals("yes") || (answer.equals("Yes"))) {
              break;
          }              


          System.out.println("Enter a Name ");
          name = KB.next();
          System.out.println("Enter " + name + "'s hight in meters");
          hight = KB.nextFloat();
          while (hight <= 0.8 || hight >= 2.5) 
          {
              System.out.println(name + "must be between 0.8 and 2.5 meters");
              System.out.println("Enter " + name + "'s hight in meters");
              hight = KB.nextFloat();
          }

          // compare within loop not outside

          if (hight >= tallestHight) 
          {
              tallestHight = hight;
              tallestName = name;
          }

          // only if - not else if as they are 2 separate comparisons   
          if (hight <= shortestHight) 
          {
             shortestHight = hight;
             shortestName = name;
          }
      }

      System.out.println("The tallest persone is " + tallestName + " at a hight of " + tallestHight);

      System.out.println("And The shortest persone is " + shortestName + " at a hight of " + shortestHight);
```